# Unable to play music in android

Tags: android

I am beginner in **android** development and I am developing an **music app** and I have queried all the **SD card** music in the list but I am unable to play the selected song through its **name or ID**. I have listed it in **listView** and by clicking on the selected item it is displaying its name which song I selected but not playing it using mediaplayer class. please help me to resolve it.

**1.** This is **First Java File** for getting List of Songs from SDcard:

public class MusicAppList extends Activity {

```
TextView tv;
 ContentResolver cr;
 Cursor cs;
Uri uri;
ListView lv;
 String tname,csong;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_app_list);

      lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.songslist);
      Songs();

}
 public void Songs(){

    cr=getContentResolver();
    uri=android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    cs=cr.query(uri,null,null, null,"title ASC" );

   final ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(cs.moveToNext()){
      list.add(cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
     }
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.mlistinterface,list);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) { 

        csong=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent i1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlaying.class);
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putInt("pos", position);
        b.putString("song", csong);
        b.putStringArrayList("songlist", list);
        i1.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i1);
        }
    });   }}
```

**2.** Below is the **Second Java File** where I am trying to play the Song.

public class MusicPlaying extends Activity {

```
TextView tv;
ImageView pre,nxt,play;
ArrayList<String>songList;
String name;
private MediaPlayer mp;
String song;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_playing);

    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.songname);
    pre=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.previous);
    nxt=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.next);
    play=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play);

    tv.setSelected(true);

    Bundle bb=getIntent().getExtras();
    name=bb.getString("song");
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(name));
    songList=(ArrayList)bb.getStringArrayList("songlist") ;
    int pos=bb.getInt("pos");
    mp=new MediaPlayer();
    Uri u=Uri.parse(songList.get(pos));

    try{
        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), u);
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.start();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ErrorPlaying", "Unable to get Reference of the song");
    }
}}
```

**3.** Logcat Error is as:-

11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996): Process: com.example.musicapp, PID: 996

11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musicapp/com.example.musicapp.MusicPlaying}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()' on a null object reference
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()' on a null object reference
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.example.musicapp.MusicPlaying.onCreate(MusicPlaying.java:60)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-15 15:57:13.503: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)

Comment: Put some code what you have treid

Comment: You can format the code in the question as text, so people can copy/paste to test it and help you. Please, consider editing your question and inserting the code as text (and formatted).

Comment: It'll be really hard to help you unless:
1) you'll post some code from the MusicPlaying onCreate: are you sure the Intent data is retrieved properly?
2) you should also post some logcat: what exceptions are you catching?
3) better to copy and paste your code instead of taking screenshots, as Tom already pointed out

Comment: Guys, sorry for the mistake  @c0rtexx . Now, I have changed my code and trying to do it in another method and this time I am getting **Logcat Error** of unable to find reference of song. Please Help!!!!!

Comment: @PreetikaKaur.... I have putted code. Please help dear.

Comment: @Tom....I have modified my code. Please help

Comment: remove that try{} catch block. You'll see your app is crashing, then go to logcat and post here all the red logs you'll find

Comment: @cOrtexx....setDataSource() cannot be used without try() & catch() block....so I have now used create() of Mediaplayer class. I have posted the logcat error.

Comment: @PreetikaKaur ,  Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to look at your **ApplicationManifest.xml** and check to make sure you have the necessary permission to write/read from the external sd card.

Typical external sd card permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And obviously, if running Marshallow or greater you'll have to ask for permission from the user which can be a pain.

Comment: Thank you for giving me your time. I have already included that code in it. I have updated my question including java files, please help me in the code.